# Kernel_thread() and thread_create(), which function actually creates a new thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, linux-kernel, pthreads

I am new to linux kernel and was just going through the boot process of kernel and found this very confusing:

```
kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND);
numa_default_policy();
pid = kernel_thread(kthreadd, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES);
```

I see that kernel_thread() calls do_fork() and as much as I know do_fork() creates an entirely new process.

So which function actually creates a new thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kernel_thread` creates kernel threads. The kernel_thread invokes `clone`.

In Linux, threads are created with `clone` and processes are created with `fork`.

fork, clone and vfork calls in turn invoke `do_fork` with different value for `clone_flags` argument.